# Unable to do profiling - Instrumenting this image requires it to run as a 32-bit process?

Tags: profiling, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to profile a Web application(Debug->Start Diagnostic Tool without Debugging) but every time it is failing with below message. Solution is set in release mode. After start profiling IE is opening with a URL `http://localhost:19394/` but getting '*Page cannot be displayed*'.

```
Warning VSP2013: Instrumenting this image requires it to run as a 32-bit process.  The CLR header flags have been updated to reflect this.
Launching web server with profiling.
Launching profilable project.
Data written to C:\Project\Report150826(1).vsp.
Profiling finished.
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
Profiling complete.
```

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise RTM and it is running under administrator privileges.

Tried to uninstall Visual studio using the command line `"C:\Setups\Visual Studio\VS 2015\vs2015.ent_enu\vs_enterprise.exe"  /uninstall /force` but uninstall also failing with error message:

```
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2999226) : The storage control blocks were destroyed.
```

Comment: Do you have the problem if you compile in Debug?

Comment: No problem in compiling and debugging, works without any issue. Diagnostic Tools works well while debugging.

Comment: It is simply telling you that no profile data was collected.  So nothing to show.  Most typical cause is your app ending too quickly, very common when you first kick the tires on the profiler.  Fixing problems with the big reinstall sledge-hammer, yikes, that's three new problems you didn't need.

Comment: You could be hitting this because of some changes to the .net native toolchain. Can you try turning off optimizations in release and see if that fixes it?